# JButton.actionPerformed: null pointer exception

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm working through a book, and the following code throws a NPE at runtime when the JButton is clicked, at the line button.actionPerformed.  I've done my best to be sure my code is exactly what is in the book, can someone point out my problem?  (the book was written for java 5, I'm using the latest java 7, this shouldn't make a difference in the following code as far as I know though)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SimpleGui implements ActionListener {
JButton button;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleGui gui = new SimpleGui();
    gui.go();
}

public void go() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton button = new JButton("click here");

    button.addActionListener(this);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.getContentPane().add(button);
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    button.setText("I've been clicked, argh!");
}

}
```

Comment: Well what's the stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is this Line:

```
JButton button = new JButton("click here");
```

Here you are creating new local `JButton` object which is [**shadowing**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the member variable `button` . Hence `button` is still `null`. You should instead use:

```
button = new JButton("click here");
```

Comment: So to fix it...if I change it to read <code>button = new JButton("click here");</code> then its not making a new object JButton, just a new object is being associated with JButton button, which already exists at that time?  So when button.setText is called, it has somewhere to go.  Is this the right way to think of it?

Comment: @nexus_2006 Yes, when you change to this code , a new `JButton` object will be created and this object will be referenced by the member variable of class `SimpleGui` . So when you call `button.setText` within `actionPerformed`, it will see that newly created object via `button` variable and hence no NPE

Answer (score 2):

In a method, you have this:

```
JButton button = new JButton("click here");
```

This create the variable, but the scope of this new variable is **inside the method**. You've already declared `button` in your class though. It should just be:

```
button = new JButton("click here");
```

Answer (score 2):

You're shadowing your variables.

You declare `button` as a class variable, but the re-declare within your `go` method, meaning that the class variable (which you reference within your `actionPerformed` method) is null

Change `JButton button = new JButton("click here");` to `button = new JButton("click here");`

Comment: As minor modification I would say ..`You declare button as instance variable (not class variable)` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well, your `JButton button;`  is still `null`.you are not assigned it anywhere in your programm

Answer (score 2):

This problem is known as "Variable Hiding" or "Hidden Variables" or "Shadowing Variables". Which means, a local variable hides another variable which has the same name. You have re defined your variable `button` inside the `go` method. Just removed the re definition from the go method, so it will work fine. Have a look at the following code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SimpleGui implements ActionListener {
JButton button;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleGui gui = new SimpleGui();
    gui.go();
}

public void go() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     button = new JButton("click here"); //Variable Re definition removed

    button.addActionListener(this);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.getContentPane().add(button);
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    button.setText("I've been clicked, argh!");
}

}
```

Since you seems to be new to the Java GUI, take the following few advises.

1. It is always a best practice to define your class variables inside the constructor
2. Use access specifiers. `private` is a good specifier for your `button` variable
3. Even though the constructor can be automatically get created (default constructor) it is a best practice to code it by your self, at least a blank one.